# Problems implementing setTimeout on jquery navigation menu with un-nested submenus

Tags: jquery, menu, settimeout, mouseenter, mouseleave

I have a menu list with submenus that are not nested for styling purposes.  Thus, I'm using mouseenter and mouseleave, together with settimeout, for hovering behavior.

Here's my html:

```
<li class="dropdown"><a href="#">Link 1</a></li>
<div class="subnav">
<ul>
<li><a href="#">Link 1.1</a></li>
<li><a href="#">Link 1.2</a></li>
<li><a href="#">Link 1.3</a></li>  
<li><a href="#">Link 1.4</a></li>  
    </ul>
</div>

<li class="dropdown"><a href="#">Link 2</a></li>
<div class="subnav">
<ul>
<li><a href="#">Link 2.1</a></li>
<li><a href="#">Link 2.2</a></li>
<li><a href="#">Link 2.3</a></li>  
<li><a href="#">Link 2.4</a></li>  
    </ul>
</div> 

<li class="dropdown"><a href="#">Link 3</a></li>
<div class="subnav">
<ul>
<li><a href="#">Link 3.1</a></li>
<li><a href="#">Link 3.2</a></li>
<li><a href="#">Link 3.3</a></li>  
<li><a href="#">Link 3.4</a></li>  
    </ul>
</div> 

</ul>
</div><!-- End topNav -->
```

And my jquery:

```
$(document).ready(function(){  

var overSubmenuFlag = false;
var timeout;
var subnav;
var offset;

$("li.dropdown").mouseenter(function(){

    clearTimeout(timeout);
    $(".subnav").hide();

    $(this).children('a').addClass("active"); //Add active class to link element

    var subnav = $(this).next("div.subnav"); //find navigation box associated with this nav tab
    var offset = $(this).position(); //Position subnav relative to nav tab
    var leftpos = (offset.left + 15) + "px";
    var toppos = (offset.top + 36) + "px";
    subnav.css( { 
        position: 'absolute',
        left: leftpos, 
        top: toppos
    });

    subnav.show(); //Reveal subnav

}).mouseleave(function() {
    clearTimeout(timeout);
    var timeout = setTimeout(function() {
        if(!overSubmenuFlag) {
            var subnav = $("li.dropdown").next("div.subnav");
            subnav.hide();
            $("li.dropdown").children('a').removeClass("active");       
        }},100);        
});
$(".subnav").mouseenter(function(){
    clearTimeout(timeout);
    overSubmenuFlag = true;  
}).mouseleave(function(){   
    overSubmenuFlag = false; 
    $(".subnav").hide();
    $("li.dropdown").children('a').removeClass("active");       
}); 
});
```

Everything works as intended, except the following: when I mouseout of one navigation header  and mouseover another header quickly, the submenu associated with the new header briefly appears then disappears.  (Mousing slowly between two navigation headers works properly).  How do I properly stop all actions associated with the setTimeout function (and close any open submenus) upon entering a new nav. header? Many thanks for any help!

Answer (score 0):

Is this your issue?

```
}).mouseleave(function() {
    clearTimeout(timeout);
    var timeout = setTimeout(function() {
    ^^^
```